# WPF SVG Icon Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to create SVG icons as resources that will easily work in multiple locations such as a `Button`, a `Label`, and as the `Icon` in a `FileMenuItem`?

**Example**

*App.xaml*

```
... 
<Application.Resources>
    <Icon x:Key="MyIcon" Data="...PathData..." />
</Application.Resources>
...
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
...
<MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" Icon="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
...
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
</StackPanel>
...
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried defining the icons as `Geometry` and a `Path` but both have complications. In the case of `Geometry` you have to specify a `Path` element and set it's `Data` property which adds a bunch of cruft to the code. Using a `Path` gets around this in some cases but for the `FileMenuItem` I found that I have to wrap the path in a `Canvas` or a `Border` again adding some cruft to the code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After doing some research and experimentation I ended up creating a `UserControl` that wraps a `Path` in a `ContentControl` then providing a couple `DependencyProperty`s so that the icon's `Data` and `Stretch` properties can be set.

**The Code**

*SvgIcon.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class SvgIcon : UserControl
{
    public SvgIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Geometry Data
    {
        get { return (Geometry) GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public Stretch Stretch
    {
        get { return (Stretch) GetValue(StretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StretchProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(Geometry), typeof(SvgIcon));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StretchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(SvgIcon));
}
```

*SvgIcon.cs*

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root" ...etc...>
    <ContentControl>
        <Path Data="{Binding Data, ElementName=Root}" Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=Root}" Stretch="{Binding Stretch, ElementName=Root}" />
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

**Example Usage**

*App.xaml*

```
... 
<Application.Resources>
    <myns:SvgIcon x:Key="MyIcon" Data="...PathData..." Foreground="Black" />
</Application.Resources>
...
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
...
<MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" Icon="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
...
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />
</StackPanel>
...
```

There are a couple benefits of using the `UserControl` approach, mainly that styles can be easily applied to the icon. However one minor pain point is applying styles to the icon outside of the resource file, such as changing the color in the file menu. Below is an example of how this can be achieved.

*App.xaml*

```
... 
<Application.Resources>
    <myns:SvgIcon x:Key="MyIcon" Data="...PathData..." />
    ...
    /*Default Icon Style*/
    <Style TargetType="myns:SvgIcon">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Style>

    /*Style icons used as content*/
    <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="BlueIcon">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="myns:SvgIcon" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type myns:SvgIcon}}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    ...
</Application.Resources>
...
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
...
<MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" Icon="{StaticResource MyIcon}" Style="{StaticResource BlueIcon}" />
...
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" Style="{StaticResource BlueIcon}" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" Style="{StaticResource BlueIcon}" />
</StackPanel>
...
```

There may be other clever solutions to this, however this worked very well for what I was looking to achieve.